# Docker compose is not opening up port for connection on one server but works the other way

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, port

I have a docker compose file that starts several services. I run this on a build-server.

```
version: '3'
services:
  screeps:
    image: screepers/screeps-launcher
    volumes:
      - ./config.yml:/screeps/config.yml
      - screeps-data:/screeps
    ports:
      - 21025:21025/tcp
    environment:
      MONGO_HOST: mongo
      REDIS_HOST: redis
    restart: unless-stopped

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8081:8081

  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  graphite:
    image: graphiteapp/graphite-statsd
    volumes:
      - graphite_data:/opt/graphite/storage/whisper
    restart: unless-stopped

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
      - ./examples/stats/grafana.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
      - ./examples/stats/grafana.prov.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/default.yaml
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: unless-stopped      
    
  stats-agent:
    image: ags131/hosted-agent 
    environment:
      GRAPHITE_HOST: 'graphite'
    volumes:
      - stats-agent:/app
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  setup-stats-agent:
    build: examples/stats/.
    volumes:
      - ./examples/stats/setup.json:/setup.json
    restart: "no"

volumes:
  redis-data:
  mongo-data:
  screeps-data:
  graphite_data:
  grafana_data:
  stats-agent:
```

Running  `docker-compose up -d` starts the services. Mongo express (on port 8081) and graphana (on port 3000) are available but the service on port 21025 is not possible to get to. The server is saying the port is open and listening,

```
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 21025
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:21025 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 9846/docker-proxy
tcp6 0 0 :::21025 :::* LISTEN 9852/docker-proxy
```

From a different machine I get:

```
sudo nmap -p 21025 192.168.10.20 --reason --traceroute --script=firewalk
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-11-04 07:08 GMT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.10.20
Host is up, received arp-response (0.00013s latency).

PORT      STATE  SERVICE REASON
21025/tcp closed unknown reset ttl 63
MAC Address: 00:1A:A0:3D:D7:CA (Dell)

TRACEROUTE
HOP RTT     ADDRESS
1   0.13 ms 192.168.10.20
```

If I use the same compose file on my main PC and nmap the port from the build-server the port is open (so this says to me that it is not my network).

I can also telnet into the build server on the 21025 port.

How can I get this port available for use as I have rebuilt the server from a base Mint image so it is not a customisation I have made.

Edit:
Output of iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1239 packets, 81262 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    19924 7860K DOCKER-USER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2    19924 7860K DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    15184 7570K ACCEPT     all  --  *      br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4     4494  270K DOCKER     all  --  *      br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
5      246 20349 ACCEPT     all  --  br-cbad15949f05 !br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
6     4488  269K ACCEPT     all  --  br-cbad15949f05 br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
8        0     0 DOCKER     all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
9        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
10       0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1195 packets, 78196 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        5   236 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cbad15949f05 br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.4           tcp dpt:21025
2        1    44 ACCEPT     tcp  --  !br-cbad15949f05 br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            172.18.0.6           tcp dpt:3000

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      246 20349 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  br-cbad15949f05 !br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  docker0 !docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3    19924 7860K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      br-cbad15949f05  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      docker0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
3      246 20349 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    19924 7860K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Could it be the firewall? what does `iptables -L` give? Also, what doe you mean by "the service on port 21025 is having problems"? What's the symptom, other than the closed port in nmap?

Comment: @ChristianFritz Thanks for pointing out iptables. I have updated the question. I used the term "having problems" as I was not sure how to describe the issue. The server says the port is open but other computers on the network are seeing it as closed.

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure exactly what caused the issue but after a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` on both the server and my local the connection now works.

For anyone facing something like the in the future, check this first before loosing sleep.